# Login authentication using token error Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

```js
 userAuthentication(userName, password) {

        let headers = new Headers();
        var data = "username=" + userName + "&password=" + password + "&grant_type=password";
        // var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-urlencoded','No-Auth':'True' });
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-urlencoded');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        headers.append('No-Auth','True');
        
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT');
        return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + 'token', data, { headers: headers  })
        .pipe(map(data => data.json()),
        catchError((error: any) => {
          throw error;
        }));
      }
    }
```

I am using angular on client side and asp.net mvc on server side.I an facing an error Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Please add error details and add your API code also.. so that i can give you a solution

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :) Please ask a question.

Comment: <Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:49445/api/token'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No type was found that matches the controller named 'token'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>

Comment: It should point to startup.cs

Comment: add your API ... (restful service) where you add something like this... MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",

Comment: I already wrote those lines in my RouteConfig.cs

Answer (score 0):

The Error you got is because you don't have required permissions to access API
add this line inside your API code

you have to install cors first

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

after add this line inside your API

```
 config.EnableCors();
```

"config" refers to httpconfiguration class

you will now able to access your API